# React / TypeScript error when updating array using setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am looking to modify a property of one of the items in the array using the updater returned from setState. The function is passed as props to the child, who then call this with their own index to change their status.

```
  const tryMarkHabitAsComplete = (index: number) => {
    let list: HabitType[] = [...habitList];
    let habit = {
      ...list[index],
      isComplete: true,
    };
    list[index] = habit;
    setHabitList({list});
  };
```

**When running with
`setHabitList(list);` the array gets cleared and becomes undefined, so I am unable to use it after I call this function once.**

The error that keeps appearing is:

`Argument of type '{ list: HabitType[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<HabitType[]>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'list' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<HabitType[]>'`

I am treating the state as immutable and attempting (I think) to set the state. When debugging, everytime I click I empty the array for my habitsList. Further up, I define the state as:

`const [habitList, setHabitList] = useState<HabitType[]>([]);`

If I try to setState in other ways, the array becomes undefined or blank and loses information. I should clarify, this is a side project written w/ react-native.

MRE Edit:

2 components in a react-native app, discarding css & irrelevant imports:
**Chain.tsx**

```
export type HabitType = {
  text: string;
  index: number;
  isComplete: boolean;
  tryMarkHabit: (index: number) => void;
};

const Chain = (props: any) => {
  const [habitList, setHabitList] = useState<HabitType[]>([]);

  // Set the initial state once w/ dummy values
  useEffect(() => {
    setHabitList([
      {
        text: "1",
        index: 0,
        isComplete: false,
        tryMarkHabit: tryMarkHabitAsComplete,
      },
      {
        text: "2",
        index: 1,
        isComplete: false,
        tryMarkHabit: tryMarkHabitAsComplete,
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  // Only is previous item is complete, let habit be marked as complete
  const tryMarkHabitAsComplete = (index: number) => {
    let list: HabitType[] = [...habitList];
    let habit = {
      ...list[index],
      isComplete: true,
    };
    list[index] = habit;
    setHabitList(list);
  };

  let habitKeyCount = 0;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {habitList.map((habit) => (
        <Habit key={habitKeyCount++} {...habit} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Chain;
```

**Habit.tsx**

```
import { HabitType } from "./Chain";

const Habit = ({ text, index, isComplete, tryMarkHabit }: HabitType) => {
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={complete ? styles.completeHabit : styles.uncompleteHabit}
      onPress={() => tryMarkHabit(index)}
    >
      <Text style={styles.chainText}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Habit;
```

When I press a habit, it calls tryMarkHabitAsComplete successfully, however it appears to clear the array - the array afterwards becomes undefined as far as I can tell.

Comment: Change `setHabitList({list});` to `setHabitList(list);`

Comment: Your state is an array, so when you pass `{ list }` to your updater you are mutating the state shape. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @NicholasTower This doesn't work unforunately, it ends up clearing the habitList when I call this function

Comment: @DrewReese Doing it that way because other SO posts do it that way, and doing it the way Nicholas Tower suggested clears the array when I call the function.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "clears the array"? It doesn't make any sense. Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Something else is happening more than just a simple state update. What and where is `tryMarkHabitAsComplete` being called.

Comment: @DrewReese editted to include my attempt at an MRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

If I had to guess I'd say you've a stale enclosure of your `habitList` state in the callback, which itself is a stale enclosure in your state.

## Solution

I suggest to instead use a functional state update in your handler. A functional update allows your state to be updated from the previous state, not the state from the render cycle the update was enqueued in. It's a small, subtle, but important distinction.

I also suggest to not enclose the handler in an enclosure in state either. Just pass it to `Habit` as a normal callback, this way you avoid any stale enclosures.

```
const Chain = (props: any) => {
  const [habitList, setHabitList] = useState<HabitType[]>([]);

  // Set the initial state once w/ dummy values
  useEffect(() => {
    setHabitList([
      {
        text: "1",
        index: 0,
        isComplete: false,
      },
      {
        text: "2",
        index: 1,
        isComplete: false,
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  // Only is previous item is complete, let habit be marked as complete
  const tryMarkHabitAsComplete = (index: number) => {
    setHabitList(list => list.map((habit, i) => i === index ? {
      ...habit,
      isComplete: true,
    } : habit);
  };

  let habitKeyCount = 0;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {habitList.map((habit) => (
        <Habit
          key={habitKeyCount++}
          {...habit}
          tryMarkHabit={tryMarkHabitAsComplete}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

## Edit for `isComplete` Style

`Habit` should just consume the passed `isComplete` prop to set the desired CSS style.

```
const Habit = ({ text, index, isComplete, tryMarkHabit }: HabitType) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={isComplete ? styles.completeHabit : styles.uncompleteHabit}
      onPress={() => tryMarkHabit(index)}
    >
      <Text style={styles.chainText}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I'm quite new to react, it's going to take a while to unpick everything that's been written here :)

This does indeed stop the application from crashing, however when I debug, the array doesn't change i.e. I call tryMarkAsComplete for item at index 0, the isComplete returns false.

Comment: The Habits don't get updated right away - I think this is because the state on them doesn't change. Is it worth returning true/false from tryMarkComplete (I still need to add some checks in there) which will set the state of the Habit?

Comment: @dev_11ccon When you say the `isComplete` returns false, what exactly do you mean? What, where, and how are you debugging? React state updates are asynchronous, it doesn't immediately update, but rather is processed between render cycles.

Comment: My bad, ignore that, forgot setState() isn't instant. I mean the Habits themselves don't change colour to their appropriate css when they're rerendered(?) but I think this is because there's nothing telling React to update these in the Virtual DOM.

Comment: Okay, I added a useEffect to tell react to update the value in setState so the css is conditoinally changed in the Habit. I've accepted this answer, as it was 100% the solution to the problem and works great. Thanks for the help, a lot more to learn.

Comment: @dev_11ccon That is likely due to the fact that `Habit` was setting the style prop based on some local component state that never updated. You can directly consume the `isComplete` prop to set the style.

Comment: Yep, I can see your edit to the answer. Thanks for the help :) This is the much more obvious & clean solution.